# move axis labels ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have produced a fact graph in ggplot2 and the x axis title (bottom) is touching the scale values slightly (it's worsened when I plot to .pdf device).  How do I move the axis title down a smidge?

```
DF<-structure(list(race = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("asian", 
"black", "white"), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"), 
    score = c(0.0360497844302483, 0.149771418578119, 0.703017688328021, 
    1.32540102136392, 0.627084455719946, -0.320051801571444, 
    0.852281028633536, -0.440056896755573, 0.621765489966213, 
    0.58981396944136, 1.95257757882381, 0.127301498272644, -0.0906338578670778, 
    -0.637727808028146, -0.449607617033673, 1.03162398117388, 
    0.334259623567608, 0.0912327543652576, -0.0789977852804991, 
    0.511696466039959), time1 = c(75.9849658266583, 38.7148843859919, 
    54.3512613852158, 37.3210772390582, 83.8061071736856, 14.3853324033061, 
    79.2285735003004, 31.1324602891428, 22.2294730114138, 26.427263191766, 
    40.5529893144888, 19.2463281412667, 8.45085646487301, 97.6770352620696, 
    61.1874163107771, 31.3727683430548, 99.4155144857594, 79.0996849438957, 
    21.2504885323517, 94.1079332400361)), .Names = c("race", 
"gender", "score", "time1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))


require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(DF, aes(score, time1, group=gender))
p + geom_point(aes(shape=19)) + facet_grid(race~gender) + scale_x_continuous('BLAH BLAH') + 
scale_y_continuous('Some MOre Of theat Good Blahing')
```

In my data BLAH BLAH is touching the numbers.  I need it to move down.  How?

Comment: Hmmmm. Can you expand a bit on what it looks like or post an example image, cause it seems to look fine when I run this. Might be specific to the platform/device/image size.

Comment: @joran I couldn't post the image or the data because I'm using someone else's data.  I couldn't get the problem to replicate outside of this data set though so I did the best I could.

Comment: No problem...I see you got the pointer to adjusting the justification. I was just intrigued cause I couldn't replicate it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can adjust the positioning of the x-axis title using:

```
+ opts(axis.title.x = theme_text(vjust=-0.5))
```

Play around with the -0.5 "vertical justification" parameter until it suits you/your display device.

Comment: Remembering that opts and theme_text are deprecated these days. You should use theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5))

Comment: Is there an equivalent that changes the positioning horizontally, while preserving the arrangement of the text? hjust seems to change the text justification and I'd like to just change the location.

Comment: Since at least ggplot 2.0.0 the vjust parameter has been superseded by [margins](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1435). Margins can be specified for top (t), right (r), bottom (b), and left (l) to position text vertically and horizontally. So to move text down you would use `theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20))`.

Answer (score 13):

This is an easy workaround, based on the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26798286/6052272)

Just add a line break; `\n`, at the start of your axes title; `xlab("\nYour_x_Label")` (Or at the end if you need to move your y label).

It doesn't offer as much control as Eduardo's suggestion in the comments; `theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5))`, or use of `margin`, but it is much simpler!

Answer (score 3):

I would like to note that this is not my answer but @JWilliman - their answer is in the comments on @Prasad Chalasani answer. I am writing this as the current upvoted answers did not actually work well for me but @JWilliman's solution does:

```
#Answer   
+ theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20))
```

This is because `theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 0.5))` has been superseded and now moves the title/label a fixed distance regardless of the value you put in.