# Moving ggplot x axis label text in a spider diagram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset. Note that these are fictitious values:

```
Farm    CO2Fert CO2Manure   CO2Feed CO2Housing  CO2Fuel CO2Other
Best    2.187635996 0.670289261 0.773605214 2.415801361 1.180859203 2.876050311
Worst   4.240789564 0.503797793 1.884548328 5.114791701 3.411847194 5.150085802
User    1.189743632 2.852713125 0.419821994 0.630429463 2.982960729 1.489036959
```

I have been asked to draw a spider diagram of these values. Having looked at fmsb and ggradar I have for a number of reasons decided to start from scratch instead. So, I have the following code (not currently sure if all the libraries are necessary):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)
library(tibble)
library(data.table)

data <- fread("C:/myData/ExampleFootprintData.csv")
dat2test <- melt.data.table(data, c("Farm"), c("CO2Fert", "CO2Manure", "CO2Feed", "CO2Fuel", "CO2Housing", "CO2Other"))

thePlot <-  ggplot(data = dat2test, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=Farm, color= Farm)) + ## Define data and colour column
  geom_polygon(fill = NA) + ## make the lines meet
  coord_polar() ## Make it round
```

The chart appears as follows:
[image: Image of simple spider diagram]

As you can see the labels are not fully onto the plot surface. Looking at the examples around on the internet (e.g. [the main text I've taken my code from](http://www.r-chart.com/2016/10/the-grammar-of-graphics-and-radar-charts.html)) this appears not to be addressed anywhere. There is an interesting solution to this [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/curve-text-around-coord-polar-plot/938), and I am considering using it, but my eventual labels are likely to be long and descriptive. I would like them to be shown horizontally as they are now with line breaks as appropriate, but so that they fit on the chart.

So far, I have not got very far with this. using `theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5))` or similar does not work, but if I use margins as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454243/move-axis-labels-ggplot), e.g.  `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = -20)))` all that changes is that the x axis title moves inwards into the plot area which expands, but the labels are still outside of the plot:

[image: new plot using margins for x axis labels]

How do I force ggplot to keep my labels inside the physical area of the plot?

dput of the data:

```
structure(list(Farm = c("Best", "Worst", "User"), CO2Fert = c(2.187635996, 
4.240789564, 1.189743632), CO2Manure = c(0.670289261, 0.503797793, 
2.852713125), CO2Feed = c(0.773605214, 1.884548328, 0.419821994
), CO2Housing = c(2.415801361, 5.114791701, 0.630429463), CO2Fuel = c(1.180859203, 
3.411847194, 2.982960729), CO2Other = c(2.876050311, 5.150085802, 
1.489036959), NO3Fert = c(2.19509301, 1.848317101, 1.643695528
), NO3Manure = c(2.452857906, 3.153028268, 1.922113286), NO3Grazing = c(0.037698451, 
4.452847769, 2.546101867), NH4Spreading = c(2.880954824, 2.60492997, 
3.186211336), NH4Storage = c(1.178815284, 4.893388111, 2.432823901
), NH4Grazing = c(0.509207305, 2.998872111, 4.444466334), NH4Housing = c(2.523406518, 
5.255666955, 1.287199958)), .Names = c("Farm", "CO2Fert", "CO2Manure", 
"CO2Feed", "CO2Housing", "CO2Fuel", "CO2Other", "NO3Fert", "NO3Manure", 
"NO3Grazing", "NH4Spreading", "NH4Storage", "NH4Grazing", "NH4Housing"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000120788>)
```

Comment: provide data with `dput(dat2test)`.

Comment: [does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241182/how-to-make-geom-text-plot-within-the-canvass-bounds)

Comment: I have added my data at the bottom of the question. I'm looking at your link to see if it resolves the issue. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried `thePlot <- thePlot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust="inward", hjust="inward"))` but if I read your link correctly these settings for `vjust` only apply to `geom_text`. The above introduces an error (NAs introduced by coercion) but does not change the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possible work around:

```
library(grid)

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(thePlot))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
grid::grid.draw(gt)
```

#### result:

[image]

Comment: That is an interesting solution. At the moment, my plot building code is in a function that returns a ggplot object to a Shiny app, which then renders it in a plotOutput. I'm not sure that using this method I could return a similar object...? I'm going to see if I can make this work. Thank you.

Comment: Yes this works if I put the `grid::grid.draw(gt)` part in the renderPlot function as the final call, and keep the rest of the code in the function (i.e. pass `gt` back as the function result. Thank you for this.

Comment: glad to help bro.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Simply add an annotation layer and remove y axis text

    thePlot <-  ggplot(data = dat2test, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=Farm, color= Farm)) + 
      geom_polygon(fill = NA) + 
      coord_polar()+
      annotate('text', x=.5, y=c(1,2,3,4,5), label=c(1,2,3,4,5))+
      theme(axis.text.y = element(blank),
            axis.tick.y = element(blank))
```