# How to write the label into the plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with the labels on the y axis (after using coord_flip)
Here is a reproducible example

```
Names <- c("ExampleA","ExampleB","ExampleC","ExampleD", "ExampleE", "ExampleF","ExampleG", "ExampleH")
Counts <- c(4,3,2,1,-1,-2,-3,-4)
Type <- c("X","X","X","X", "Y","Y","Y","Y")
df <-data.frame(Names,Counts, Type)

ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(Names,Counts), y=Counts, fill=Type))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_minimal()
```

I want the labels to be written next to the bars. Meaning that "ExampleA/B/C/D" etc. should be written right next to the bars and not listed on the y axis.
Or in visuals:
What I have

[image: What I have:]

What I want
[image: What I want:]
(Credit Li et al. 2021 https://doi.org/10.3389/fimmu.2021.694801)

I tried:
[ggplot: put axis text inside plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406829/ggplot-put-axis-text-inside-plot)
which didn't work.

This

```
geom_label(label=Names, parse=TRUE)
```

is close but not really what I want (and also for the real data only works when I type out every single name into a vector which I'd like to avoid if not nescessary).
I was hoping that there is something along the lines of

```
geom_label(label=Names, position="inside")
```

or

```
scale_x_discrete(position = "inside")
```

would be possible, but thus far I could not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated to match OP's required output and long names.

Have rearranged x and y subjects from original so that we can avoid `coord_flip` and read the graph as is, rather than transpose x and y.

Made text positioning more robust using both `hjust` and `nudge_x`, the former aligns the text and the later provides the padding between the text and the end of the bar.

As for the long text this is managed by creating extra space either side of the plot using `expansion` in the call to `scale_x_continuous` and setting the text size to 3 in the call to `geom_text`. An alternative would be to edit the text to include a line break but this may be problematic where there are many bars.

```r
library(ggplot2)

Names <- c("ribonucleoside triphosphate biosynthetic process" ,"purine ribonucleoside triphosphate biosynthetic process" ,"ATP biosynthetic process" ,"proton motive force-driven ATP synthesis" ,"NADH dehydrogenase complex assembly" ,"mitochondrial respiratory chain complex I assembly" ,"innate immune response" ,"antigen processing and presentation of peptide antigen")
Counts <- c(4,3,2,1,-1,-2,-3,-4)
Type <- c("X","X","X","X", "Y","Y","Y","Y")

df <-data.frame(Names,Counts, Type)

ggplot(df, aes(Counts, reorder(Names,Counts), fill=Type))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(label = Names, x = 0),
            size = 3,
            nudge_x = ifelse(Counts < 0, 0.05, -0.05),
            hjust = ifelse(Counts < 0, 0, 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.75, 0.75)))+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Close, is there a way to write the labels next to the bars on the other side? So that they end/start at 0

Comment: Sorry I missed that, will change the answer!

Comment: Set `x = 0` explicitly within `geom_text()`, but outside of `aes()`

Comment: I tried this on my dataset (which has 74 datapoints and not just 8) and for some reason the text is shifted. (I cant add a plot to a comment so Ill try to rectreate it using text with- beeing the bar and . beeing an empty space)  some look like this: ------............label, some like: -------label, others: -------.......label. Any idea as to why that is? The only reasoning I have is that its 74 points and not just 8.

Comment: That's going to be a vey condensed graph! To be honest I'm not really sure I can picture what the problem is. I have removed the `scale_y_continuous` argument from the answer as this is no longer required. Possibly the elements in the `Names` variable need tidying up? Can you include a subset of your actual data that replicates the problem?

Comment: The problem is the length: Names <- c("ribonucleoside triphosphate biosynthetic process"
           ,"purine ribonucleoside triphosphate biosynthetic process"
           ,"ATP biosynthetic process"
           ,"proton motive force-driven ATP synthesis"
           ,"NADH dehydrogenase complex assembly"
           ,"mitochondrial respiratory chain complex I assembly"
           ,"innate immune response"
           ,"antigen processing and presentation of peptide antigen")
Counts <- c(4,3,2,1,-1,-2,-3,-4)
Type <- c("X","X","X","X", "Y","Y","Y","Y")

Comment: With these names (GOterms) it shows a shifted image for some reason

Comment: Thanks for the new name set, see updated answer, which seems to cover it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could create new variables `x2` and `y2` as below and use them in `annotate` function to generate the expected plot

```r
df <-data.frame(Names,Counts, Type) %>% arrange(desc(Type), desc(Names), Counts) %>% 
mutate(x2=row_number(),
       y2=ifelse(Type=='X',-0.4,0.4)) %>% 
  arrange(Type,Names,Counts)

ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(Names,Counts), y=Counts, fill=Type))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_minimal() + annotate(geom = 'text', y=df$y2, x=df$x2, label=df$Names) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())

# output

      Names Counts Type x2   y2
1 ExampleA      4    X  8 -0.4
2 ExampleB      3    X  7 -0.4
3 ExampleC      2    X  6 -0.4
4 ExampleD      1    X  5 -0.4
5 ExampleE     -1    Y  4  0.4
6 ExampleF     -2    Y  3  0.4
7 ExampleG     -3    Y  2  0.4
8 ExampleH     -4    Y  1  0.4
```

[image]

Comment: This also works for the example data. But for the real data (with longer names see coment above) it fails for some reason. There the names are split and partially written inside the coloumns.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the `Names` is lengthy then we can decrease the size of the labels in `annotate()` as below

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(Names,Counts), y=Counts, fill=Type))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_minimal() + annotate(geom = 'text', y=df$y2, x=df$x2, label=df$Names, size=3) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]